# Deriving the formula for length of function curve.

Tags: calculus, arc-length

In my textbook the first step in deriving the length of a function curve is to the the sum
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sqrt{(x_{i}-x_{i-1})^{2}+(f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1}))^{2}}$
Now my text continues to derive the formula in a clear and understandable way. However i tried to do it myself and this is the logic i used: as $n\to\infty$ then $x_{i}\to x_{i-1}$ and $f(x_{i})\to f(x_{i-1})$ so we can write the previous sum as the following integral
$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{(x-x)^{2}+(f(x)-f(x))^{2}}$ which is equal zero. So where did i make the mistake? Thank you

Edit sorry to post this question as i was able to see my mistake right after posting it, the first sum does not have a delta x term so it's not reinman sum.
[I used a similar logic to what's described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyPzh.jpg)  here the textbook approximated $x_i$ and $x_{i-1}$ by $x_{i}^*$

Comment: As $n\to \infty$, even though $x_i \to x_{i-1}$ and $f(x_i) \to f(x_{i-1})$, also the number of terms in the sum becomes infinite, and adding an "infinite amount of infinitesimal terms" can produce a constant. In other words, you can't just take the limit inside the sum. Besides, it seems that you think an integral is just a sum of infinite terms (that's a _series_), but it is actually the limit of infinite terms, in which also the terms themselves approach zero.

Comment: HappyDay tgank you for replying

Comment: Your mistake was assuming their difference is zero, when in fact they are not.

Comment: Hayst check the image i added

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is approaching $b$, that does not mean $a$ is equal to $b$. In this case, $f(x_i)$ is approaching $f(x_{i-1})$, it does not mean both are equal. The same goes for $x_i$ and $x_{i-1}$.

So their difference is not $0$, instead it is something really small we will call  $dy$ and $dx$.

$$f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) = dy$$
$$x_i-x_{i-1} = dx$$

Substituting...
$$L =\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$$
Factor out $(dx)^2$...
$$L =\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{(dx)^2(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)}$$
We can take the square root of $(dx)^2$ and change $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to $f'(x)$.
$$L =\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}  \ \ dx$$

Comment: Check the image i added to my question

Comment: You keep saying check the image, but you've gotten two perfectly adequate answers. Please be more specific about what your question is.

Comment: Charles Hudgins in the image i provided the textbook replaced $x_i$ and $x_{i-1}$ by $x_{i}^*$ and then converted the sum to integral. I was trying to do the same here